# How to save files in same folder applescript

Tags: applescript, automator, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to use automator to run an applescript to save illustrator files in their native folder with a new name. Any help with my applescript on this? Have to declare a path.

```
on run {input, parameters}
  tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    set allMyItems to every path item of current document whose fill color is {cyan:0.0, magenta:0.0, yellow:0.0 black:100.0}
    repeat with myItem in allMyItems
      set fill color of myItem to {cyan:0.0, magenta:0.0, yellow:0.0 black:0.0}
    end repeat
    set theDestination to path to parentfolder
    save current document as eps
    close current document
  end tell
  return input
end run
```

Comment: Please do not provide screenshots or links to screenshots of your code.  Edit your question to include the code as text.

Comment: You need to put four spaces before each line of code so it can format properly.  I have done this for you.

Comment: It was formatted right in automator, I also added set theDestination to path to parentfolder after end repeat. Still asking for a path though. Any thoughts?